# Translated placeholder value not pulling through to Symfony 4 form field

Tags: php, yaml, twig, symfony4, symfony-forms

```
{% trans_default_domain "admin" %}

{% form_theme leadForm _self %}

{{ form_row(leadForm.phonenumber) }}
```

My form field is defined as:

```
    $builder
        ->add('phonenumber', TextType::class, [
            'label' => false, 
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'change.lead_form.placeholders.phonenumber'
            ]
        ])
```

and I am setting the translation domain:

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'translation_domain' => 'admin',
    ]);
}
```

`admin.en.yml` includes the following:

```
change:
    lead_form:
        placeholders:
            phonenumber: Required
```

However, the placeholder does not show when I set it in the form definition. I can pull it in if I use the `attr` attribute in Twig, but i'd rather do it in the form definition.

Answer (score 0):

I clearly missed this in [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder), however it looks like the "attr" was dropped in a recent version of Symfony.

This will work in Symfony 4.

```
        $builder
            ->add('phonenumber', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'change.lead_form.placeholders.phonenumber'
            ])
```